# How to project the outline of an object when viewed from a particular angle onto another object and use that outline to cut through the object

Tags: modifiers, knife-tool

is there any way to generate a cut throw an object (target) so that the whole projection of another object (template) fits ?

For example something like in the image: I have some 3d models (templates - animals or furniture for example) and I have some target object (a cube for example). So I want to use the whole projection of the object to cut a hole through the cube so that the template object can go from one side to the other.

[image]

Boolean modifier is the first thing that comes to my mind, but it only works with the intersection of the object, I would like to achieve something similar but with the projection.

Thanks!

Edit: I already tried knive project but for some reason when trying to use a complex mesh as the template object I have this error
"No other selected objects have wire or boundary edges to use for projection"

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are after, but wouldn't giving the projected mesh some depth (solidify modifier) solve that?

Comment: To get this clear... you want to project the outline of an object when viewed from a particular angle onto another object, then use that outline to cut through it?

Comment: Exactly @Psyonic!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Object Line Art from the Grease Pencil

This creates an outline of an object in the direction the camera is pointing.

Create a camera pointing in the direction you want:
[image]

Select the object you want the outline of and choose Add - Grease Pencil - Object Line Art
[image]

A new Line Art is created, add a shrinkwrap modifier to it and choose your target object - It helps to have everything lined up first
[image]

Next apply the modifier stack and convert it to Polygon Curve
[image]

Then convert that to mesh
[image]

You will now have a new mesh object in the exact shape of the object outline.
Sometimes it will need some cleanup as there might be overlapping edges.
[image]

Then you can use it as your cutter object
[image]

Hope this is what you were looking for...
Happy Blending

Comment: It worked! Cool. Now I need to script this, it is going to be... interesting.